# How do you verify QoS for a router?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, qos

I am using a TP-Link Archer C60. I have put my TV in the High Priority List (70%) for a smooth IPTV/Netflix experience. However, I see my TV buffering when my phone starts downloading anything although it has a less priority (20% rule).

• How can I verify if QoS is working?

Secondly, for the connected devices, Traffic Statistics page also shows only 10MB received traffic while I've downloaded 100MB+ on my phone during a given time interval. Is it a normal behavior for router to not catch it?

Comment: I Use jperf & Wireshark for this. Use jperf to mimic problematic traffic via tcp/udp port number. Use Wireshark to see how it's being prioritized / shaped on it's way out.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart but how do you actually see all packets from all devices connected to a router on a single computer/wireshark instance?

Comment: I think in your case, unless that router supports port mirroring, you would need the machine-in-the-middle setup mentioned here https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet